# Nested routes — creating records that are async

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple Ember app with 2 models related to each other: `parent` and `record`:

```
// parent model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  records: DS.hasMany('records', { async: true })
});

// record model
export default DS.Model.extend({
  parent: DS.belongsTo('parent')
});
```

Record routes are nested under parent routes and parent template contains `link-to` records and an `outlet` to render the content in. Records template contains simple `{{#each}}` loop.

Here is the records index route that is responsible for setting model:

```
// records index route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('parent').get('records');
  }
});
```

When I load `parent/records` route all records load/render fine. The problem starts when I try to create new record; which I do in records index controller:

```
// records index controller
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['parent'],

  actions: {
    createRecord: function() {
      var newRecord = this.store.createRecord('record', {
        parent: this.get('controllers.parent.model')
      });

      newRecord.save();
    }
  }
});
```

After I create new record it doesn't appear inside my records index template. If I open Ember inspector I can see the record there, it even has the correct parent record assigned.

Here is the answer I am getting from the server after creating the record:

`{ "record": { "id": 1, "parent_id": 1 }}`

I think the problem occurs because of record index route or response from the server; if I change route like this, new records appear as intended after creation (although thats not what I want; I want just the records that belong to the parent record):

```
// records index route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('record');
  }
});
```

I am on Ember 1.6.1 and Ember Data beta 8. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, your index route grabs an Array of models — it doesn't know that they have been updated or removed.

There are two ways to solve this: use a filter array or update the array manually.

Here is a link to question on the same subject:

[Ember template not updating from arraycontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624133/ember-template-not-updating-from-arraycontroller)

Comment: I've sticked to updating an array manually, although I don't like either solution much. I will mark your answer as accepted until a better one appears ;-) Thanks for your help!